# HTML <td> overflow onclick

Tags: html, onclick, overflow, html-table

Since I may not explain the context, I will just link it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932787/td-overflow-onclick-html)

I have a table. In that table, there is an overflow of information, in certain cells. When I make a cell clickable (onclick -> function) it is limited to the cell.

My question: How can I make all the overflow clickable?

Comment: With JavaScript/jQuery you can multi-match to check for `<td>`'s which match the overflow criteria.

Comment: Make an element inside each `td` that holds your data, and attach the click handler to that. On a side note, you should design your table in a way so that overflow doesn't occur.

Comment: @Asad I know it's bad practice. But I don't know how else to do it. I can imagine that it would be some if-statements that "marks" the layers. The problem is that I need the cells to contain booking information. Now I got an array that runs through every single cell and asks my mysql database if there is any booking with that date and start time.